# Add a sub-directory as another repo

Tags: git

Let me first describe the problem. Assume that I have the following directories structure:

```
Repo-A
  - ...
  - sub-dir-A
    - ...

Repo-B
  - ...
  - sub-dir-B
    - ...
Repo-C
  - ...
  - sub-dir-C
    - ...
...
```

What I want to do is the following: I want to make `Repo-A`, `Repo-B`, and also `Repo-C` all private, which contains all **and** `sub-dir-A`, `sub-dir-B` and `sub-dir-C`'s contents, while making `sub-dir-A`, `sub-dir-B` and `sub-dir-C` into another *public* repo. i.e.,

```
Repo-A
  - ...
  - sub-dir-A
    - ...

Repo-B
  - ...
  - sub-dir-B
    - ...
Repo-C
  - ...
  - sub-dir-C
    - ...


Repo-Public
  - sub-dir-A
  - sub-dir-B
  - sub-dir-C
```

My approach now is rather naive, I just simply create another separate public repo and **copy-pasting** all the `sub-dir-<A, B, C, ...>` into that new directory and manually update them, which is a pain.

I'm not sure whether this is doable, especially I'm familiar with working with `sourcetree` but not the command line for `git`. (But if the only option is using the command line to manipulate things around, then I can learn it for sure). I have looked into the symbolic link and things like submodule and subtree in `git`, but can't find a useful tutorial. They're usually talking about how to **split** two directories, while I want to make them integrated somehow.

Comment: git submodules are the way to go

Comment: @DanielA.White - submodules must to be avoided as much, as possible, as one of shiftiest part of Git

Comment: You **have** to search more carefully and read using brain - subtree IS the definitive answer (with small headache after successful transition)

Comment: Ok, it's my bad that I forget another important thing: I want to link **several** such sub-directory (with different parent directories) into one huge repo. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Copy sub-dir-<A, B, C, ...> into their own separate public repositories using [`git subtree split`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/7976758). Next time you change something in these subdirectories in repos <A, B, C, ...> do `git subtree push` to update one of those separate public repo.

Create a new repository <Repo-Public> and copy  sub-dir-<A, B, C, ...> into it using either [`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) (and later update using `git submodule update --remote`) or [`git subtree add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) (update with `git subtree pull`).

Comment: It's quite complicated actually, is there a simpler workaround? Since I don't want multiple sub-dir-repo flying around in my github.

Comment: @PingbangHu I don't think there is a simpler way. Your task is too complex for Git which is intended to pull/push commits and branches for whole repositories, not files and directories. (G)it has problems with separate subfolders.