# Partial git synchronization between two unrelated repositories

Tags: git, synchronization

Let's say I have a repository with a folder hierarchy like this one:

```
repo1
    +- project1
    +- project2
    +- project3
    +- project4
    +- project5
    +- ...
```

There is another repository `repo2` which should contain only a subset of projects/folders from the `repo1`:

```
repo2
    +- project1
    +- project2
    +- project4
```

I am looking for the most efficient/simple/reliable (pick any two) way to occasionally synchronize `repo1` and `repo2`.

Conditions:

- I specifically do not want to add `repo1` as a remote repo for `repo2`. Parts of `repo1` that are not supposed to be synchronized should not be accessible.
- The `repo2` repository is essentially a snapshot repository. It will only be updated to include the recent changes from `repo1`. There will never be any direct, manual commits made to it.
- Synchronization does not need to happen on every commit in `repo1`. In fact, the synchronization should only be triggered either explicitly or on some `repo1` event that occurs less frequently (such as tagging).
- It is not necessary to synchronize all individual commits made in `repo1` since last synchronization. When synchronizing, it will be enough to just take the current versions of relevant `repo1` projects and push them to `repo2`.

I guess I'm looking for a less cumbersome version of this approach (ideally not having to do anything locally):

1. checkout `repo1` locally
2. checkout `repo2` locally
3. copy relevant projects/folders from `repo1` working directory to `repo2` working directory
4. commit changes in `repo2`
5. push local `repo2` commits to its origin

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833606/7976758

Comment: That solution requires quite a bit of repo restructuring that I'd try to avoid if I could. In any case, thanks for the suggestion.