# Clone a subdirectory of a submodule in git

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-clone

I wish to create a submodule in my repository, and inside that submodule I only want to clone ONE folder to use as a dependency.

**For example if this is my current state:**

```
main repository
│__README.md
│__file001.txt
```

```
dependency repository
|__src
|__include
```

**I want to have:**

```
main repository
│__README.md
│__file001.txt
|__dependency repository (submodule)
   |__include
```

How is it possible to do it in git?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833606/7976758

Comment: Another solution to try is sparse checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+sparse+checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not!

The submodule is a whole repository, so you have to clone it enterely.