git subtree - merge the whole subrepository with multiple subfolders into the main repository
I have read and used git subtree functionality a lot.
Especially are useful these links
Add subdirectory of remote repo with git-subtree
If I have main repo:
base/folder1
base/folder2

And I have sub repo (repo2):
base/folder3
base/folder4

I cant change the structure of the folders, as this is inherit from some other SCM platform, and build process expects this folder structure.
How I can use git-subtree to have both of the subfolders (folder3 and folder4) inside my main repo and in the same time to track changes from a subrepo? (that is where git subtree should come into place)
I couldn't find way for this.
Ideally with sub-tree I would like to accomplish a repo with this structure:
base/folder1
base/folder2
base/folder3
base/folder4

I have tried with:
$ git subtree add --prefix . repo2 master --squash
prefix '.' already exists.
$ git subtree add --prefix base repo2 master --squash
prefix 'base' already exists.

If I add into some other folder like "repo2"
  $ git subtree add --prefix repo2 repo2 master --squash

Then this would work but then I would have structure:
base/folder1
base/folder2
base/repo2/folder3
base/repo2/folder4

which is NOT what I want.
Is this possible to achieve with git and subtree functionality?
Thank you

I don't think your desired structure could be achieved using git subtree. git merge --allow-unrelated-histories perhaps.

@phd I also didn't find that using git subtree is possible for this scenario.
But in this case if I change something for "repo2" inside the "repo1" I cannot push it to "repo2" from "repo1" - like that is the case when using the "git subtree push", correct?

Yep. What you want cannot be done in a simple way. Could be implemented using a number of intermediate repositories like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833606/7976758 . Split you repo2 into 2 separate repos using git subtree push with folder3 and folder4 at the root, git subtree pull these repos into repo1 inside base. When changing anything in folder3 or folder4 in repo1 do git subtree push into the corresponding intermediate repo and from it pull into repo2. Quite cumbersome but possible.

Thanks for the response, I am aware of this workaround, but as I mentioned unfortunately it is not applicable because I can't modify repo definition because already building processes are configured for this structure, many development teams are using these repositories etc. I would know how to do it with folders divided into separate repositories... git subtree would be used in this case without issue, but as I said, my repository definition must start with "base" folder

You don't need to modify repo2, you only create two additional intermediate repos.

@phd why don't you provide full answer to this very interesting question? and I suppose it will be useful for other people as well... So my basic requirements are: 1. repo2 must remain in the format as it is 2. I want to incorporate repo2 within the repo1, with all its subfolders (starting with /base folder) and be able to push changes to repo2 from repo1 (which is supported using the git subtree)

I already answered once with the link above — nobody cared. Do you think next time it will be better? Ok, I'll try…

I don't know any simple way to do what you want. Git doesn't really allow working with separate subdirectories. The entity is the entire repository, the unit of work is a commit which includes a copy of the entire working tree. git subtree allows to export/import subdirectories but you need intermediate repositories to store them.
You can export subfolders from repo2 but you cannot do that in one step — git subtree allows only one prefix. So you need to create two empty intermediate repositories. Let's say their hosting is at <URL>; lets name these new repos r2f3 and r2f4 to remember their content came from repo2 folder3 and f…4 (if <URL> is actually local filesystem or SSH-accessed filesystem the new repos must be bare because you will push into them; repos at Git hostings are always bare).
First you export subfolders from repo2 into these new repositories:
$ cd repo2
$ git subtree push -P base/folder3 <URL>:r2f3
$ git subtree push -P base/folder4 <URL>:r2f4

The very repo2 stays unchanged except for two new branches, the result of git subtree split ran by git subtree push.
Now import them into repo1:
$ cd repo1
$ git subtree add -P base/folder3 <URL>:r2f3
$ git subtree add -P base/folder4 <URL>:r2f4

When you have new commits in repo2 you do re-export and re-import:
$ cd repo2
$ git subtree push -P base/folder3 <URL>:r2f3

$ cd repo1
$ git subtree pull -P base/folder3 <URL>:r2f3

When you have new commits in repo1 that touch folder3 or 4 you do re-export and re-import in the reverse direction:
$ cd repo1
$ git subtree push -P base/folder4 <URL>:r2f4

$ cd repo2
$ git subtree pull -P base/folder4 <URL>:r2f4

Cumbersome, yes. But works and could be automated with scripts.
